# Automapper conditional map from multiple source fields

Tags: c#, automapper

I've got a source class like the following:

```
public class Source
{
    public Field[] Fields { get; set; }
    public Result[] Results { get; set; }
}
```

And have a destination class like:

```
public class Destination
{
    public Value[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to map from EITHER `Fields` or `Results` to `Values` depending on which one is not null (only one will ever have a value).

I tried the following map:

```
CreateMap<Fields, Values>();                
CreateMap<Results, Values>();                

CreateMap<Source, Destination>()                
            .ForMember(d => d.Values, opt =>
            {
                opt.PreCondition(s => s.Fields != null);
                opt.MapFrom(s => s.Fields });
            })
            .ForMember(d => d.Values, opt =>
            {
                opt.PreCondition(s => s.Results != null);
                opt.MapFrom(s => s.Results);
            });
```

Only issue with this is that it looks if the last `.ForMember` map doesn't meet the condition it wipes out the mapping result from the first map.

I also thought about doing it as a conditional operator:

`opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Fields != null ? s.Fields : s.Results)`

But obviously they are different types so don't compile.

How can I map to a single property from source properties of different types based on a condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a **`ResolveUsing()`** method that allows you for more complex binding and you can use a **`IValueResolver`** or a **`Func`**. Something like this:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Values, mo => mo.ResolveUsing<ConditionalSourceValueResolver>());
```

And the value resolver depending on your needs may look like:

```
 public class ConditionalSourceValueResolver : IValueResolver<Source, Destination, Value[]>
    {
        public Value[] Resolve(Source source, Destination destination, Value[] destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            if (source.Fields == null)
                return context.Mapper.Map<Value[]>(source.Results);
            else
                return context.Mapper.Map<Value[]>(source.Fields);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great, that worked thanks! I think one of my issues was after moving away from the static version of the mapper, I wasn't sure how to actually do a map inside another map. Now I know I can get to it from the context. Thanks!

Comment: What's frustrating is when you find yourself using `ResolveUsing` for almost every mapping, which leads to some ugly code and makes you wonder if using AutoMapper is better than just building a factory

Answer (score 3):

Following @animalito_maquina [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970126/4752488).

Here is an update for [8.0 Upgrade](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing):

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Values, mo => mo.MapFrom<ConditionalSourceValueResolver>());
```

And to save you time, ValueResolvers **are not supported** for [Queryable Extensions](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options)

Answer (score 2):

ResolveUsing is not available, try this.
It's working for me

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()   
.ForMember(opt => opt.value, map => 
map.MapFrom((s, Ariel) => s.Fields != null ? s.Fields : s.Results));
```